# Trying to store images generated on canvas into a zip with JS, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm generating a large quantity of assets on canvas so saving each one individually isn't feasible. Furthermore I'm generating the files on a canvas with a "webgl" context so `getImageData` isn't an option here. [I found a lib that can generate a zip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) of as many files as I need, but I'm having trouble with it:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var zip = new JSZip();
var img = zip.folder("images");
var pixels = new Uint8Array(
  gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4
);
gl.readPixels(
  0,
  0,
  gl.drawingBufferWidth,
  gl.drawingBufferHeight,
  gl.RGBA,
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  pixels
);
img.file("myfilename.png", pixels, { base64: true });
zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function(content) {
  saveAs(content, "asset.zip");
});
```

The resulting zip file is the correct size (as in, large enough to represent the images within) but each image is unreadable. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}

uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
blob = dataURItoBlob(uri)
img.file(counter + ".png", blob);
```

Just toyed with various formats until it worked. Incidentally this solution is fairly performant.